# Why were Cathode ray tubes first invented?

Tags: electricity, atomic-theory, technology

Cathode ray tubes have played a very important role in the development of physics around 1900. They have also served as a key component in old-fashioned TVs.

This is great and all, but what was the motivation for inventing them in the first place? They have been around since before J. J. Thomson did anything with them, and I have a hard time finding the earliest device that shows these so-called cathode rays.

This leaves me with two questions:

1. What was the earliest device that we now know creates a stream of electrons?
2. What was the motivation for inventing such a device?

Comment: A lot of info already in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray